# Some 2htdp/image functions are not working

Tags: racket

I was following along with my racket practice when i tried drawing a circle and got an error.

```
    #lang racket
    > (square 40 "solid" "slateblue")
    square: this function is not defined
```

I tried rectangle and works just fine

```
> (rectangle 40 40 "solid" "slateblue")
> .
```

Some other functions like wedge and triangle/saa also didn't work.

I'm using DrRacket version 8.8. I already tried switching to advanced student without avail.

What am I missing? I already included the htdp/image techpack and read the documentation but I can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two htdp/image teachpacks- [htdp/image](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/image.html) and [2htdp/image](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html).

`htdp/image` is deprecated and doesn't contain `square` function. Use `2htdp/image`:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)
(square 40 "solid" "slateblue")
(rectangle 40 40 "solid" "slateblue")
```

Comment: That was it, that you!